# COPY command in Dockerfile. How to copy from one level up

Tags: docker, copy

I am trying to copy files in Dockerfile.

Here is how my folder looks like.

```
main.R <- my main executable file
app <- folder with Dockerfile.
```

In Dockerfile I have the following commands:

```
RUN mkdir -p ~/application
COPY "../" "application/"
WORKDIR "application/" 
ENTRYPOINT ["Rscript", "main.R"]
```

This does not work, it gives me error `Fatal error: cannot open file 'main.R': No such file or directory

If I move `main.R` file inside `app` folder everything works fine. How can I make it work without moving files.

Comment: From the directory up, run `docker build -f app/Dockerfile .`; the `COPY` path will be relative to that parent directory, so you can change it to `COPY ./ application/`, and not be copying things from outside the context directory.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thank you so much. I am doing it in Azure and in YAML file I have  variable set `dockerfilePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/app/Dockerfile'` and later it use like this `dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)`. I am guessing it should set proper context, but it is not working.